# Python: import local package in the project root instread of the one installed by pip

Tags: python, import, python-packaging

I am using Python 3.7 in Ubuntu. I installed [gym](https://github.com/openai/gym) (or any other packages) via pip. The package, gym, in installed in "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/rlgpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gym". If I use "import gym" in Python code, then it imports the gym package installed by pip.

I downloaded the source code of gym and modified the code. Assume the folder name of the modified gym package is "gym", and I put the "gym" folder under the root of a project. In the project, how do I import the gym from the modified package under the project root, instead of the one installed by pip under "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/rlgpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gym"?

Comment: check you "path". Do "import sys; print(sys.path)". Your project root should come first (empty string) - so it should look like `['', `/home...`. It'll be looking in each dir sequentially until it finds that package.

Comment: That is, local packages take precedence over installed ones, if you don't do anything to `sys.path`.